# Flutter & Firebase: Send File as Image

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-storage, flutter

I want to send photo selected by user in my app to Firebase Storage. I have a simple class with property `_imageFile` which is set like this:

```
File _imageFile;

_getImage() async {
    var fileName = await ImagePicker.pickImage();
    setState(() {
        _imageFile = fileName;
    });
}
```

after that I send photo like with this code:

```
final String rand1 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
final String rand2 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
final String rand3 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('${rand1}_${rand2}_${rand3}.jpg');
final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.put(_imageFile);
final Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
print(downloadUrl);
```

My problem appears in firebase console:

[image]
Photo has `application/octet` type instead of `image/png`. Is there any way to fix that? Or maybe is it a good behaviour and I should not care here about types? What about downloading this photo?

My `dependencies`:

```
image_picker: 0.1.1
firebase_storage: 0.0.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [firebase_storage](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_storage/lib/firebase_storage.dart#L32) plugin does not currently have an API for specifying metadata of the uploaded file. If you wanted to add this, it would be fairly straightforward and you could send us a pull request. However, there's nothing wrong with `application/octet-stream`; it is a general mime type for binary files that should render fine in most situations.